# how to make onchange event happened in code-behind in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Suppose I have a textbox Mytbx and I have a javascript for its onchange event. I hook it up in code behind in Page_Load event like:

```
Mytbx.Attributes.Add("onchange", "test();")
```

Then I changed the text in code-behind for this textbox like (in a button click event for example):

```
Mytbx.Text = MyValue
```

I expect onchange event fired. but actually, it's not. When I click on the button to change value for Mytbx, nothing happening.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Is your text box a server control or HTML control?

Comment: Why would changing the text on the server trigger a client-side javascript event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

onchange will only be triggered on client side when you directly type something and leave the textbox. So nothing will happen when you set the textbox value in code behind.

If you want to handle the text change event on client side:

```
<script>  
     function test(txt){
         alert(txt.value);
     };
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" onchange="test(this);"></asp:TextBox>
```

If you want to handle text change event on server side, you could do this:

HTML:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txt_OnTextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

CS:

```
protected void txt_OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Do something
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the code behind delegate from firing via the JS onChange() method?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing client and server processing. If you change the textbox on the SERVER, there is no client code to run yet becuase you haven't posted the form back. If you have javascript code that has to run when you change something on the server, you need to register that Javascript function to run when the page loads when your postback is complete. Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript(v=vs.110).aspx