# call TextChange Event at server side using JavaScript in asp.net with c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to write `textchange event` at server side using `javascript`.

I wrote that without using `javascript`. 
I set the textbox properties of `AutoPostback:true`.

I want to write this in `onchangeevent of javascript`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function CallTextChange() 
         {            
 __doPostBack("TextBox1", "TextChanged");
         }
</script>
```

call 'CallTextChange'  function where you want

for more detail see this [how to make onchange event happened in code-behind in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201727/how-to-make-onchange-event-happened-in-code-behind-in-asp-net)