# Is it possible to add the 'onchange' html/js event in backend when generating html? If so, how?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net

I'm generating a bunch of DDLs. When one of these has its value changes, I need to disable all of them until back-end OnSelectedIndexChanged event is done. I can re-enable the lists here in back-end.

Due to how the page postback works in asp.net, I can't simply do dropdownlist.enabled = false in the backend. So, I want to try to use JS 'onchange'.

The onchange I want to add, keep in mind I don't have any dropdownlists added like this, so I can't do it this way. Mine are generated in the backend:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="TestDDL" **onchange="somejs"** runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Here's a bit of the back-end where the dropdownlist is put together, could I somehow attach the 'onchange' event shown above to this ddl here?

```
    Dim ddl As New DropDownList()
    ddl.ID = folder.folderId

    ' Set options
    SetOptions(ddl)

    ' Set active option
    SetActiveOption(folder.folderId, ddl)

    dropdowns.Add(ddl)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make onchange event happened in code-behind in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201727/how-to-make-onchange-event-happened-in-code-behind-in-asp-net)

Comment: Look into `Attributes.Add`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick way, all controls have the [Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.attributes?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_WebControls_WebControl_Attributes) property which allows you to add any extra attributed to a control. You could then add your JS in there.

If your JS need to do a postback, then that's a different story.